# how to apply joins against my table

Tags: php, laravel-5

**when user enter coutry america and course master than select country and institute/university name from institute table if the university offer master course than select its course(master) from degree table institute_id is foreign key in degrees table:

Institute Model

```
protected $table = 'institutes';

protected $fillable = [
    'user_id','email', 'contact', 'country','about','name','city'

];


public function degree()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Degree','institute_id');

}
```

Degree Model

```
  protected $table = 'degrees';

protected $fillable = [
    'institute_id','description', 'course', 'fees','session','education_req'

];
```

**  link for the site to understand the problem more clear in this site if you enter country america for master than it shows all the unviserity of america who  offer master degree **
[link](http://www.mastersportal.eu/search/#q=kw-master%20america%7Clv-master,preparation%7C!dg-prebachelor&order=relevance)

Comment: so what is your question here  ?

Comment: i want to write this query in laravel 5.2 against this query $query = "SELECT institutes.id,institutes.country,degrees.institute_id,degrees.course FROM institutes INNER JOIN degrees on
institutes.id=degrees.institute_id WHERE degrees.course ='master' AND institutes.country='islamabad' " ;